# ng-disabled directive on html elements

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I need to know, if ng-disabled attribute can be applied on html elements, or only on form elements?

Like can we apply ng-disabled on a div or smart-table(Bootstrap) cells in a html table.

Comment: I tried but it is not working

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when the div or table is "disabled"?  ng-disable simply puts an attribute called "disabled" on the element when its expression evaluates truthy.  When used on input controls, this element has an effect of disabling the control, however there's no similar built-in meaning for disabled on other elements.  You'll have to use CSS, or JS to make the disabled attribute behave the way you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

The question is what is your goal?

The purpose of disabling an element is to prevent input events on it, and to show that it is disabled by adding styles to it.

`ng-disabled` will only prevent input events on input elements (input, textarea, select, buttons).

If you have a click event on an element that typically doesn't have a click event (like a div) you can use something like this:

`<div ng-click="disabled || do_something()" ng-class="{disabled: disabled}">Click Me</div>`

And style accordingly.